# Cloudfront caching responses with Cache-Control : no-cache, no-store set from origin on traffic spikes(load testing with k6)

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control

Current cache policy is set to

```
Minimum TTL : 0
Maximum TTL : 31536000
Default TTL : 0
```

**Origin Response**
We have a specific url pattern for which we are setting the `Cache-Control`: `no-cache, no-store` response header from origin.

**Expected behaviour:**
The expected behaviour according to the docs [Managing how long content stays in the cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationDownloadDist) is all the requests should reach origin server.

**Test Condition**
We have been using k6 for load testing and found that under 10 rps for 10s, we get about `65% cache hit from cloudfront` and only `35% cache misses` based on the `X-Cache` header.
We have tried many different combinations of TTL and other possible `Cache-Control` headers but nothing worked.

**Expected Resolution**
We want all the requests with that specific pattern to reach our origin servers.

Comment: Perhaps you're seeing the [Simultaneous requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-traffic-spikes) behavior?

Comment: "according to the docs" - which docs? Any link and quote?

Comment: @Marcin Added the docs link

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks for the suggestion. I tried setting `Headers: None` in `cache key settings` of cache policy. The cache misses have increased to 98%. But still there are 2% cloudfront hits happening. This was tested with 10 rps. But the cache hits seem to increase with increase in rps. Eg, 91 % miss and 8% hit with 20rps

Comment: Increasing cache hits with increasing rps is what you would expect if the issue was Cloudfront handling simultaneous requests. As far as I know there is no way to disable that behavior.